# Image from base64 encodes bad in Spring and not shown React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, base64

So, i have an opportunity in my application to add dish to menu. When a add it, i encode it in base64 and send to my server Spring Boot. It decodes this image and saves in db as blob. When i need to get my dishes, i encode images again and sent to the frontend(React). But i get bad encoding:

This is my encoding in React

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...
```

I send it to my controller:

```
 @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Dish> saveDish(@RequestBody Dish dish) {
        Dish response = dishService.save(dish);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

@Override
    public Dish save(Dish dish) {
        log.info("Saving dish: {}", dish);

        DishEntity dishEntity = DishEntity.builder()
                .image(Base64.decodeBase64URLSafe(dish.getImage()))
                .price(dish.getPrice())
                .title(dish.getTitle())
                .description(dish.getDescription())
                .category(dish.getCategory())
                .count(1L)
                .totalPrice(dish.getPrice())
                .build();

        DishEntity savedDish;
        try {
            savedDish = dishRepository.save(dishEntity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new OperationFailedException("Save dish method failed");
        }

        return Dish.builder()
                .id(savedDish.getId())
                .image(Base64.encodeBase64String(savedDish.getImage()))
                .price(savedDish.getPrice())
                .title(savedDish.getTitle())
                .description(savedDish.getDescription())
                .category(savedDish.getCategory())
                .count(savedDish.getCount())
                .totalPrice(savedDish.getTotalPrice())
                .build();
    }
```

When i get dishes, a make reversed things. And this is base64, i get from the server:

```
dataimagepngbase64iVBOR....
```

And therefore, images are not rendered

I made a method to check image rendering if i send correct values, wrote method, which adds symbols, and when i change base64 encoding from `dataimagepngbase64iVBOR....` to `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...`, a get error in console:

[image]

Comment: is `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...` what `dish.getImage()` returns? I see no place where you extract the base64 string form the image url. And where exactly does `dataimagepngbase64iV...` come from?

Comment: look, in react i encode like that `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...` then send it to spring, spring decoded it to byte[] and saves to MySql as blob, and when i get data from spring, i need to encode this byte[]. and `Base64.encodeBase64String(dishEntity.getImage())` returns `dataimagepngbase64iV...`

Comment: but if you get `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...`, which is a Data URL, containing a Base64 String, and treat it like a Base64 string `Base64.decodeBase64URLSafe(dish.getImage())` then it is wrong. A Data URL (`data:image...`) contains Base64 data, but it is not Base64. The Base64 image starts after the `Base64,` with `iVBOR...`. I guess that is your problem here.

Comment: wow, thank you man, you realy helped me